# Can onActivityResult() be called before onCreate()?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

Can `onActivityResult()` theoretically be called before `onCreate`? I know it can be called before `onResume()`, but let's consider this extreme case:

1. activity A is running and starts activity B for a result
2. activity B opens
3. the device is running low on memory, so it destroys activity A
4. activity B finishes with a result

What happens now? Does activity A get re-created before receiving the result, or does it receive the result before `onCreate()`? Is this guaranteed to be in the same order each time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will commonly see this if you are opening an app to scan a barcode or take a photo or video. The `Activity` you launch to do that requires a lot of resources so Android kills the OS process hosting your app.

When the `Activity` you launched wants to return the result to your app, the following occurs:

- Android creates a new OS process for your app (because it killed yours and needs a new one)
- Android instantiates the `Application` instance (or your app's custom one) and calls `onCreate()` on that
- Android instantiates a new instance of the `Activity` that will get the result (the one that called `startActivityForResult()`)
- Android calls `onCreate()` on the new `Activity`. The `Bundle` passed to `onCreate()` in this case is the `Bundle` most recently used to the save the `Activity` instance state (from `onSaveInstanceState()`).
- Android calls `onStart()` on the new `Activity`
- Android calls `onActivityResult()` on the new `Activity`
- Android calls `onResume()` on the new `Activity`

Comment: Thanks, this is just what I needed. Just to clarify - are these calls in the same order each time?

Comment: Yes, always in this order.

Answer (score 0):

Those case Use

```
registerForActivityResult()
```

> Activity Result APIs decouple the result callback from the place in
> your code where you launch the other activity. As the result callback
> needs to be available when your process and activity are recreated,
> the callback must be unconditionally registered every time your
> activity is created, even if the logic of launching the other activity
> only happens based on user input or other business logic

more details refer [Getting a result from an activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result#kotlin)